# Disable form authentication in sitecore 9

Tags: federated-authentication, authentication

I am using `Sitecore federated authentication` with azure AD to login to Sitecore. But, I can also use my Sitecore password to log in using form authentication.

Is there any `OOB solution` to disable form authentication in Sitecore so that the user is forced to use SSO. I have already tried disabling form authentication and setting form mode to none.

Comment: Just hide the fields ?

Comment: I am asking about an oob solution which can be managed via some settings. I understand some workaround have been provided in https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13673/sitecore-federated-authentication-on-cm-server-remove-login-form but i am trying to disable not override form authentication